# Objective C Add Announcement to a List in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, post, sharepoint-2010

I'm building an iOS app for my school which uses Sharepoint 2010 for the website. I need the app to add items (announcements) to an announcements page. Is there anyway to go about this in Objective C. I have the correct permissions and I have the authentication working I just don't know how to post the announcement.

I have had a brief look into using html's POST but it doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks in advance.
Johann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here again almost a year later just incase someone is looking into this.

Sharepoint (2010 is what I was using) has a `REST API` more information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx).

Thanks.